# created data not getting sent to Mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am doing a website in Node.js with express and MongoDB with a productpage displaying products from a products collection. I

i am having trouble getting the data persisted in mongodb, when i create a new product. The entries are saved i the db, as timestamp and ObjectId is saved but the data ie. productname, category, description and price does not get saved. The route below works in postman and all data gets saved when i create a product from there.

PostRoute for create product:

```
router.post("/admin/productPage", async (req, res) => {

    const product = new Product(req.body)

    try {
        await product.save()
        console.log(req.body)
        res.status(201).redirect("/adminProductPage")
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
});
```

This is the Schema:

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        trim: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        price: Number
    },
    productImage: {
        type: String,

    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Here is the modal that i am using to create the product:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="createProjectModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header d-block">
                        <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Indtast product information</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="admin/productPage" method="POST" id="newProductForm">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="name" class="form-label">Navn</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="category" class="form-label">Kategory</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="description" class="form-label">Beskrivelse</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="price" class="form-label">Pris</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitBtn">Gem Produkt</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What am i missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are you using an appropriate middleware to parse your form's data? e.g. you used to have to `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); `

Comment: Could you tell us what do you see in `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: @Brendan Bond. That did the trick. Thx a million..  :-)

Comment: If you are using Express v4.1.6.0, you can use `app.use(express.urlencoded())` (instead of `body-parser`).